# Disable Backspace and Tab key on disabled InputText on KeyUp event

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I've already tried writing a javascript function for backspace key...but it doesn't seem to work.

Below is the inputtext element from where the javascript function is called:

```
<td Id="TDBooking" style="width:10%">
        <apex:inputText id="idInputDelivery" value="{!PWTData.TDelivery}" style=" width: 50px; " maxlength="{!if(isMonth, 3, 5)}" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this);" onKeyUp="preventBack(this);calDeliveryData();CalculateOtherData(this);"/>
 </td>
```

Here is the javascript function:

```
function preventBack(evt)
        {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if(charCode ==8 )
            {
                console.log('===called on backsapce');
                var target1 = event.target || event.srcElement;
                var keyvalue = event.which || event.keyCode;
                var eventtarget =  target1.nodeName;
                var readonlycheck = target1.readOnly;
            if(readonlycheck)
                {
                    //evt.preventDefault();
                    return false;

                }
            console.log('==1st last true===')
            return true;
          }      

        }
```

I think it may not be recognizing the keyup event on disabled fields and the other javascript functions are called even if the function is returning false.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the click event will be fired on a disabled control. What you want to do here?

Comment: Yes...but if you focus on the disabled field and press backspace the other javascript functions are getting fired...I want to stop that!

Comment: I tried but there is no keypress or keyup evenet for disabled fields. Also I could not see the disabled attribute in your code `<apex:inputText id="idInputDelivery" value="{!PWTData.TDelivery}" style=" width: 50px; " maxlength="{!if(isMonth, 3, 5)}" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this);" onKeyUp="preventBack(this);calDeliveryData();CalculateOtherData(this);"/>`

Comment: Similar inputtext fields are there which are disabled...the functionality is if you key in values in the editable field...values will be automatically enter in the disabled fields based on multiplication...if you focus on the disabled field and press backspace or tab...still the multiplication is happening....tried this function on "onfocus" as well!

Comment: How are you able to focus disable field. Check this fiddle link I created https://jsfiddle.net/u02xbs85/1/. If you press tab key from text1 it move to Text3 skipping Text2.

Comment: Sorry the fields are readonly...not disabled...and tab in that case works...also if you highlight text in the readonly field and press backspace then also, the keyup event is getting fired and the values are getting changed...cant use disabled fields!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50875/discussion-between-saroj-bera-and-keyser-soze).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever I understand from your comments is that you want to avoid focus from the read-only fields. There are two things you can try one is set the `tabindex` to some `-1` and remove the focus on the element as soon as it gets it by using `this.blur()`. See this fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/u02xbs85/2/ for the implementation and check the difference in behaviour by removing `onfocus="this.blur();" tabindex="-1"`.